# javaFX sceneBuilder with IntelliJ

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, javafx

JavaFX Scene Builder is not integrating properly into IntelliJ IDE for me. I got it to work on my windows 7 computer but on my mac it is giving me problems. First when i specify the path of JavaFX scene builder to the /applications/scenbuilder/ it does not display the scene in the IDE. Second when scene builder stand alone launches and i make modifications to the .xml file in my intelliJ project, all the .xml generated is errored in red in IntelliJ with the "Cannot resolve symbol" error text displayed.

Is there a step I'm missing to implement scene builder in IntelliJ on mac. I am not sure why this isn't working. I have followed setup correctly. Has anyone else had this problem? The error displayed in intelliJ is "java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException"

```
Java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX.sceneBuilder.SceneBuilderCreatorImpl.create(SceneBuilderCreatorImpl.java:35)
 at org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX.sceneBuilder.SceneBuilderEditor.addSceneBuilder(SceneBuilderEditor.java:204)
 at org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX.sceneBuilder.SceneBuilderEditor.updateState(SceneBuilderEditor.java:191)
 at org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX.sceneBuilder.SceneBuilderEditor.initSceneBuilder(SceneBuilderEditor.java:174)
 at org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX.sceneBuilder.SceneBuilderEditor.selectNotify(SceneBuilderEditor.java:252)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite$1$1.run(EditorComposite.java:148)
 at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:124)
 at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:99)
 at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CoreCommandProcessor.executeCommand(CoreCommandProcessor.java:85)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite$1.selectionChanged(EditorComposite.java:154)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor34.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
 at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusConnectionImpl.deliverMessage(MessageBusConnectionImpl.java:116)
 at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.doPumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:368)
 at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:355)
 at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.pumpMessages(MessageBusImpl.java:341)
 at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.sendMessage(MessageBusImpl.java:334)
 at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl.access$200(MessageBusImpl.java:42)
 at com.intellij.util.messages.impl.MessageBusImpl$2.invoke(MessageBusImpl.java:223)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.selectionChanged(Unknown Source)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite$3.run(EditorComposite.java:229)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl$15$1.run(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1055)
 at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.a(FocusManagerImpl.java:672)
 at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.d(FocusManagerImpl.java:656)
 at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.f(FocusManagerImpl.java:626)
 at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.access$200(FocusManagerImpl.java:60)
 at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl$11.run(FocusManagerImpl.java:522)
 at com.intellij.util.ui.UIUtil.invokeLaterIfNeeded(UIUtil.java:2361)
 at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:500)
 at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(FocusManagerImpl.java:495)
 at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.doWhenFocusSettlesDown(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:64)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl$15.run(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1052)
 at com.intellij.openapi.util.BusyObject$Impl$Simple.execute(BusyObject.java:123)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl.notifyPublisher(FileEditorManagerImpl.java:1048)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite.a(EditorComposite.java:224)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite.access$600(EditorComposite.java:67)
 at com.intellij.openapi.fileEditor.impl.EditorComposite$MyChangeListener.stateChanged(EditorComposite.java:410)
 at com.intellij.ui.JBTabsPaneImpl.a(JBTabsPaneImpl.java:81)
 at com.intellij.ui.JBTabsPaneImpl.access$100(JBTabsPaneImpl.java:36)
 at com.intellij.ui.JBTabsPaneImpl$2.selectionChanged(JBTabsPaneImpl.java:67)
 at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.fireSelectionChanged(JBTabsImpl.java:965)
 at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.executeSelectionChange(JBTabsImpl.java:918)
 at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl._setSelected(JBTabsImpl.java:882)
 at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.JBTabsImpl.select(JBTabsImpl.java:864)
 at com.intellij.ui.tabs.impl.TabLabel$1.mousePressed(TabLabel.java:89)
 at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6532)
 at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
 at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
 at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4522)
 at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
 at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
 at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
 at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
 at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
 at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
 at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
 at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.c(IdeEventQueue.java:866)
 at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:650)
 at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:381)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
 at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javafx/fxml/FXMLLoader
 at org.jetbrains.plugins.javaFX.sceneBuilder.SceneBuilderKitWrapper.create(SceneBuilderKitWrapper.java:19)
 ... 84 more
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem (still do, because I didn't have time to try to fix it yet), but this is what the support answered me:

> Please see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-145806 . When
>   running on the bundled Java, it will not work since our bundle doesn't
>   include JavaFX classes, it will be fixed in the future updates. You
>   can try running under stock Oracle JDK as a workaround, see
>   https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544879 for
>   details.

Comment: o ok. I had intelliJ working with scene builder on win7. On my mac i dowloaded fx and idk through intelliJ initial setup. Maybe this is the problem? I will try switching under oracle jdk like u said. Thanks